# Keep Trailing Spaces in Column Text

Tags: excel

Is there a way to make Excel keep the trailing spaces in a column or selection? I need 16 spaces, exactly, but excel keeps removing them, unless I put a non-whitespace character. I can't get it to stick.

```
Dim c as Range
For Each c In Selection
   if c.Value <> "" Then c.value = c.value & Space(16)
Next
```

Comment: Your code works for me.  the 16 spaces are put on the end.  Maybe you have other code that is trimming the result?

Comment: The cells contain only numbers and are formatted as General. Could it be table formatting?

Comment: Ah,  You need to first change the format to text then you can add the spaces.